# Typescript eventListener fire multiple times

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a problem with an audio player I'm doing.

The thing is that when the audio is ended, the next one should be played. That works correctly, but the eventListener is firing multiple times, so its doing weird things. 
I tried with a removeEventListener, but didnt work, and I dont really know what else should I do.

This is the eventListener code, which is inside a function that checks if the audio should be played or paused, that part works correctly.

```
playPause(item,i) {
 console.log("i value", i)
    if (i <= this.array.length - 1) {
      let audioTemp = url
      if (!this.audio || this.audio.src != audioTemp) {
        if (this.audioBefore == null) {
          this.audioBefore = item;
        }
        if (this.audioBefore != item && this.audioBefore != null) {
          this.audioBefore.init = "play";
          this.audioBefore = item;
        }
        this.audio = document.getElementById('thePlayer') as HTMLAudioElement;

        this.audio.src = url
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.audio.play();
          item.init = "pause";
        }, 150)

      } else {

        if (this.audio.paused) {

          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("PLAY")
            this.audio.play();
            item.init = "pause"
          }, 150)




        } else {
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("PAUSE")
            item.init = "play"
            this.audio.pause();

          }, 150)

        }
      }
    } else {
      this.array[i].init = "pause";
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.audio.addEventListener('ended', () => {
          this.playPause(this.array[i + 1], i + 1);
      }, 300)
    });
}
```

Thanks for your time and your help.

Comment: have you tried to add this 'myEvent.stopPropagation()' to you event listener? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: I tried, but it says its that stopPropagation is not a function.
Also I think the problem is, the same event is firing again and again, and thats whats causing the problem. But I tried with removeEventListener, and that function never fires, so I dont know what to do.

Comment: have you tried to validate the whole event with an if else statement? Like, get a boolean ready to be checked in the event, that way, it does not matter if the event is triggered multiple times, as long as you can maintain the boolean variable to work as it should...Hope that I could give you an idea...

Comment: Don't see the mistake, to be honest. Did you consider to use Ionic `Events`? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/ They work like `EventListener`.